# Upgrade from 16 to 17

Tags: upgrade

I want to upgrade form 16.04 to 17.10, but I have some data on my PC, including programs, files, music, even some configurations of VPN and another tools.

After I read about this I found out that I need to make a back-up of all my data.

How can I avoid losing anything form my current system? Including the music files to my configurations. Is this possible?

Can I just copy all my data to an external HDD, install the new version and after that copy my data back?

Comment: You answered your own question by asking it, yes take your data onto a separate disk and copy it back afterwards is probably the easiest solution.

Comment: you should be able to just do a re-install (or upgrade(s)) from Ubuntu 16.04LTS to 17.10 without loosing any data.  However things can go wrong, power go out due to storm, you click on format accidently etc, so backups are worthwhile regardless.  The backup ideally won't be used; but should bad things occur you do want to have it!

Comment: @Videonauth yes, but can I copy everything like all the files form bin and so on? I know that the programs, music, documents and so on will be properly saved but I don't know what things I have to copy to have all the other (as an exmaple _git_) when I copy them back

Comment: Only your own data is important, maybe a few settings files if you have a highly customized system, but bedise that the stuff in /bin end so on you not need to backup, unless you make a full backup of the partition as is with clonezilla or the like so you can play back the whole system in case something goes wrong.

Comment: @Videonauth I want to have all of the features I installed as well. How can I keep all of my "apt-get install" available after upgrading? This is kind of an idiot question, but I didn't find a clearer way to say it..

Comment: How much 'apt-get install' stuff do you have? Three applications? Or fifty? Are any from non-Ubuntu sources? I use a fairly stock system, and re-install the few minor additions at first-need - apt is great for that. If your system is highly customized then you must do a bit of planning and preparing.

Comment: I understand that you plan to upgrade to 17.10, but I think it is not recommended. If you do not have newest hardware, you are really do not need 17.10. You will face many problems with Wayland, pseudo-Unity (GNOME Shell really) and so on. 17.10 has more cons than pros. I recommend to stay on 16.04 LTS as long as it possible (it is supported until 2021).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are multiple risks when upgrading your system. Something could go wrong, which is why you perform a backup.

Back up all your data. Then perform the upgrade. The packages you have installed will usually be upgraded and your system will work fine. Your data will still be there. Your system will be different, usually it is an improvement.

There are some third-party repositories that may be disabled automatically by the upgrade process. (This only happens if you have specifically added those third-party repositories.) If you have installed packages from those repositories, then you will temporarily lose those specific packages when you upgrade. The upgrade process will inform you of that fact. You can make a note of those packages and re-enable them after the upgrade. (If the packages don't support the latest version of Ubuntu, then you'll have to live without those specific packages.)

I always upgrade my system. It is a fairly smooth process. It might take me a day or two to get some things ironed out after an upgrade. I do make backups, but I almost never lose data in the upgrade process.

Your mileage may vary.